# Verificar data inicial e final e inserir um texto entre elas!

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mysql

Bom dia, tenho um código "pronto" em que o usuário deve cadastrar um evento que posteriormente será mostrado em um calendário, bom a primeira parte já está pronta mais a segunda está me dando problemas, eu gostaria de fazer um verificação da data inicial e final e inserir um texto (Ex: evento!!) nos dias entre essa datas,PS: as datas são adquiridas via banco de dados, todos os dados já estão gravados

exemplo: data inicio 6/6/16 data fim 16/6/16 , o texto deve aparecer em todos os dia do dia 6 ao 16

```html
        <?php
        include 'connect.php';
        $sql = "select Data_inicio, Data_fim from walldata";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $Data_in = $row['Data_inicio'];
                $Data_fim = $row['Data_fim'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['datac'])) {
            $datee = explode('-', $_POST['datac']);
            $mes = $datee[1];
            $ano = $datee[0];
            $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));
        } else {
            $mes = date('m');
            $ano = date('o');
        }
        if ($mes == date('m')) {
            $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        } elseif ($mes == '') {
            $mes = date('m');
            $ano = date('o');
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        } else {
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        }
        
        ?>
         

        <form method="post" action="date.php">
            <input type="month" name="datac" value="<?php echo $ano ?>-<?php echo $mes ?>" required><input type="submit">
            <table class="table table-striped" width="210" border="2" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px"><center>Domingo</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Segunda</center></td>
                <td width="80px" class="center">Terça</td>
                <td width="80px" class="center">Quarta</td>
                <td width="80px" class="center">Quinta</td>
                <td width="80px" class="center">Sexta</td>
                <td width="80px" class="center">Sábado</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $dias; $i++) {
                    $diadasemana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $i, $ano));
                    $cont = 0;
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        while ($cont < $diadasemana) {
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            $cont++;
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<td width='100px' height='100px'><center>";
                    echo $i;
                    echo "</center></td>";
                    if ($diadasemana == 6) {
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                ?>
            </table>


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Se tiverem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso ;D
[image: Imagem de como está atualmente!]

Comment: Preciso que seja  mais específico. Onde você quer colocar a palavra ? TIpo, em cada data ?

Comment: Sim nos dias em que o evento acontecer

Comment: exemplo, data inicio 6/6/16 data fim 16/6/16 , o texto deve aparecer em todos os dia do dia 6 ao 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o http://fullcalendar.io/, onde faz isso automático.

O código abaixo irá te ajudar.

Faz um range de datas utilizando sua data inicial e sua data final:

```
function dateRange($first, $last, $format = 'Y-m-d', $step = '+1 day'){
$dates = array();
$current = strtotime($first);
$last = strtotime($last);

while ($current <= $last) {
    $dates[] = date($format, $current);
    $current = strtotime($step, $current);
}
return $dates;
```

}

Percorre as datas adicionando o evento nos dias:

`$eventos[] = array('dataIni' => '2016-01-01', 'dataFim' => '2016-01-10', 'evento' => 'Evento Janeiro');
$eventos[] = array('dataIni' => '2016-01-09', 'dataFim' => '2016-02-5', 'evento' => 'Evento Fevereiro');`

$calendar = array();
foreach ($eventos as $evento) {
    $range = dateRange($evento['dataIni'], $evento['dataFim']);
    foreach ($range as $data) {
        $calendar[$data][] = array('evento' => $evento['evento']);
    }
}

Percorre o calendário verificando os dias e adicionando a descrição do evento nos locais.